# Fermented rice horchata

Tags: food-safety, rice, fermentation

I have been making some horchata (using white rice, cinnamon and water). I left it for a day and when I returned, it looked slightly fermented (a stream of bubbles were coming out of it and it was frothy ever so slightly). I blended and sweetened it and it tasted delicious, with a slightly tangy taste.

My question is will it be safe to eat? I see no reason why it shouldn't be, after all it is no different to fermented ginger beer, but I would like to have some advice.

Answer (score 3):

There is a pathogen, [Bacillus cereus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacillus_cereus), which can grow on rice left out at room temperature and cause food born illness.

I was unable to find any references to *proper* fermentation of horchata which is normally not fermented as far as I can tell.

You may wish to be cautious in the future.

Comment: OK thanks, I only had a few sips; but to be safe I'm going to chuck it

Comment: There are a number of rice beers found in Asia such as Amazake in Japan and Makgeolli in Korea.  Both of these rely on the use of a starter, koji or nuruk respectively, to inoculate the cooked rice with yeasts and other flavor-producing fungi.